# Parity Windows slow sync despite --warp/latest vers etc

Tags: parity, windows, warp-sync

I run Parity (latest version) on Windows and the sync is super slow.
I tried [several flags proposed here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/is-it-possible-to-make-the-parity-software-sync-faster/10470) aswell as [the warp mode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13697/windows-parity-syncing-very-slowly?rq=1), although as i understand from teh FAQ this is default now any way?!

I tried even [adjusting teh snapshot peers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/parity-warp-syncing-slow), however this now led to stopping my sync and showing "3,797,811 best block".

My start path now looks like this under windows

> "C:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity\ptray.exe" ui --warp --db-compaction hdd --cache-size 1024 --tracing off --pruning fast --snapshot-peers 16

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's `parity.exe` you want. Which version is that? How's your internet connection? How many peers are connected? Also 3797811 is pretty close to the chain head. You could still try increasing your snapshot peers.

Answer (score 2):

Partly solved the Problem:
Add the flags to the parity.exe not the ptray.exe, this increased my syncing speed by about 50%.
Nevertheless still ~1300 Block per hour is pretty slow